# Create function key for azure function from powershell

Tags: function, powershell, azure

Is it possible at all to create a function key for a just created azure function from powershell script?
I have got a release pipeline to create the whole environment for azure function and it is working fine but one part I am missing is a custom function key for the function. I don't want to use the default key. I could create the new key in the portal but I need it to be done from the script.

Comment: It would be better if you add some more details and what you've done about it till now.

Comment: Moved to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no such Power Shell cmdlet, but you could use [Function Api](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Key-management-API).

Creates or updates the key at the specified resource with an auto generated key:

```
POST /admin/functions/{functionname}/keys/{keyname}
```

Use the following Power Shell to use API.

```
$tenant = ""
$clientId = ""
$clientSecret = ""
$subscriptionId = ""

$body = @{
    "grant_type"="client_credentials";
    "client_id"=$clientId;
    "client_secret"=$clientSecret;
    "resource"="https://management.azure.com/"
}
$resourceGroup="shuiapp"
$name="shuifunction"

$authInfo = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenant/oauth2/token" -Body $body -Method Post -Headers @{"Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"} 

$publishData = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/$name/publishxml?api-version=2016-08-01" -Method Post -Headers @{"Authorization"="Bearer $($authInfo.access_token)"}

$userName = $publishData.publishData.publishProfile[0].userName
$password = $publishData.publishData.publishProfile[0].userPWD

$apiBaseUrl = "https://$name.scm.azurewebsites.net/api"
$siteBaseUrl = "https://$name.azurewebsites.net"

# For authenticating to Kudu
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username,$password)))    

# Call Kudu /api/functions/admin/token to get a JWT that can be used with the Functions Key API 
$jwt = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$apiBaseUrl/functions/admin/token" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method GET

# Call Functions Key API to get the master key 
$x = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$siteBaseUrl/admin/host/systemkeys/_master" -Headers @{Authorization=("Bearer {0}" -f $jwt)} -Method GET

$masterKey = $x.value

# create a custom function key
$functionname="HttpTriggerPowerShell1"
$v=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$siteBaseUrl/admin/functions/$functionname/keys/shui" -Headers @{Authorization=("Bearer {0}" -f $jwt)} -Method POST
$v.value 

# get function key value
$x = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$siteBaseUrl/admin/functions/HttpTriggerPowerShell1/keys" -Headers @{Authorization=("Bearer {0}" -f $jwt)} -Method GET
```

Note: You need create a new service principal and give `contributor` role. Please refer to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal).

Comment: @Y. A. Does it work now? Please let me know if you need more future help.

Comment: Sorry for not responding yet. I tried to use one of registered apps's clientId and clientsecretId. It does not work so far:         The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Comment: So my question is if I can use registered app principal at all? Or I need to create a user in AD?

Comment: I tried to add that registered app to resource group access policy and possibly assign contributor role but I don't have permissions on that level and probably because of it I don't an option to add a new policy. Is it what I need to archieve?

Comment: see my comments above please.

Comment: @Y.A. Sorry for later response. You need create a new user or service principal and give it contributor role. According to your error log, it seems your user does not have enough permission.

Answer (score 0):

You can create function keys using Az Cli: [az functionapp keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/keys?view=azure-cli-latest#az-functionapp-keys-set):

> Create a function key for an Azure Function app.
>
> ```
> az functionapp keys set `
>   -g MyResourceGroup `
>   -n MyFunctionAppName `
>   --key-type functionKeys `
>   --key-name MyKeyName `
>   --key-value MyKeyValue
> ```

If the `--key-value` is not specified, it will be auto-generated.